# The problem is how do I determine the result of the smallest number within the function, and how do I return it?

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int myNum1 = 0;
int myNum2 = 0;


int main() {


    int smaller, bigger, a, b;

    cout << " Enter two numbers :" << endl;

    cin >> a, b;

    smallerNumber(smaller, bigger, a, b);

    cout << smaller << bigger << endl;

    return 0;

}


int smallerNumber(int a, int b, int IsSmaller, int IsBigger){





    if (a > b) {
        a = IsBigger;
        b = IsSmaller;
    }
    else if (a < b) {
        a = IsSmaller;
        b = IsBigger;
    }
    else if (a == b) {
        a = IsSmaller;
        b = IsBigger;
    }
    return a;
    return b;

}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? Please describe it in more detail. What input are you giving it, what does it do, what do you expect it to do instead and what have you tried to remedy the situation so far? What were your thoughts behind writing the code as it is? For example why did you put two `return` statements one after another, what was the thought behind that?

Comment: `return a; return b;` makes *no* sense. After `return a;` the function ends and no further statements are executed.

Comment: You also needs to declare `smallerNumber()` before `main()` if you want to use it in `main()`.

Comment: `cin >> a, b;` should be `cin >> a >> b;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide if you want to modify the parameters of a function or return a **single** value.

### Modifying the Parameters

Pass the *return* variables by reference:

```
void smallerNumber(int& a, int& b, int IsSmaller, int IsBigger)
{
    if (a > b) {
        a = IsBigger;
        b = IsSmaller;
    }
    else if (a < b) {
        a = IsSmaller;
        b = IsBigger;
    }
    else if (a == b) {
        a = IsSmaller;
        b = IsBigger;
    }
}
```

Pasing by reference allows your function to modify the parameters.

### Returning Multiple Values

To return multiple values you'll need a data structure.
Here's an example using a struct.

```
struct BigSmall
{
    int bigger;
    int smaller;
};

BigSmall smallerNumber(int a, int b)
{
    BigSmall result;
    if (a > b) {
        result.bigger = a;
        result.smaller = b;
    }
    else if (a < b) {
        result.bigger = b;
        result.smaller = a;
    }
    else if (a == b) {
        result.bigger = a;
        result.smaller = a;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, what I wanted to do was modify the parameters, because the comparison for biggest or lower number had to be done within the function. I just didn't know how I was going to return them by reference.